# Is there a way to define if a field is Ever Updateable, if Update access can be granted to a field by Profile or Permission Set?

Tags: formula-field, permissions, fields, bulk-permission

Is there a way to define if a field is Ever Updateable, if Update access can be granted to a field by Profile or Permission Set?

[Field Describe information for a field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) can define if permissions can be set to a field by looking into `isPermissionable()` function result, but it doesn't say if a field can be set Update permission.

[Field Describe information for a field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) can define if field can by updated by the current user, but also it doesn't say if a field can be set `Update` permission by admin for the current user.

Is there a way to determine that some fields like Contract.EndDate or Individual.MasterRecordId is readonly and can never be set `Update` permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my package for Bulk Object and Field permission, I decide this by the following rule.

I define field as `Readonly` and not available for `Update` permission if one of the statements holds true

1. Describe field result `isCalculated()` method returns true. Which
   means this is a custom formula field

   > Returns `true` if the field is a custom formula field, `false` otherwise. Note that custom formula fields are always read-only.
2. Describe field result `isAutoNumber()` method returns true. Which
   means this is an auto number field.

   > Returns `true` if the field is an Auto Number field, `false` otherwise.
3. The field is `EndDate` for `Contract` or `MasterRecordId` for `Individual`.

Comment: What do you do with `CreatedDate` and `CreatedBy`? Or, for that matter, `LastModifiedDate` and `LastModifiedBy`?

Comment: CreatedDate, CreatedBy, LastModifiedDate and LastModifiedBy are never updateable by User. Also, although User can change OwnerId, admin cannot remove or add update access to this field, so all system fields are never updateable, that is, update access cannot be granted or removed for them

Comment: In that respect, OwnerId is actually not special. Admin cannot remove update access to any required field.

Comment: I have been looking for something is ever updatable field for a field like it is there for object but in vain. Note the logic you outlined, doens't cover some special fields which doesn't exhibit any of these characteristics but still readonly. For ex., WorkOrderLineItem.TotalPrice

Comment: probably the list of exception should be maintained manually, my list wasn't exhaustive